# Adding a frequency column to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe with TransID, prop, weeknum

It looks like this

```
A1234    a    1
B234     a    1
C333     b    1
D444     b    1
```

How can I add a new column to this dataframe which will be a count of all rows belonging to a {prop, weeknum}.  Thus in this example the new column would contan '2' for every row.

Comment: What are the column headers here?

Comment: Looks like you want `df.groupby(['prop', 'weeknum']).transform('count')`